# Adding label # 4013

Tags: civimail

I need to add a label format for a pin feed printer to be able to print membership address for the labels.  How do i find the correct entries to add this label avery #4013?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new Label via the link available at this [settings page](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/labelFormats?reset=1)